# DENSE_RANK with subquery

Tags: sql, dense-rank

I have products that come in different requests so if the same products come in 2 requests I want to return the last request id.

I have used DENSE_RANK to take unique products based on request ID but it gives me different ranks when I am using it as a subquery and I noticed that I am facing the issue if I have products that are related only to one RequestId as the following data:

> ```
> Product   StatusId    ProductID   RequestId
>     62    60                75    10
>     62    60                79    10
>     62    60                23    10
>     62    60                 7    10
> ```

the query:

```
    SELECT [Product], [StatusId], [ProductId],
                   DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [Product] ORDER BY [RequestId] DESC) ranked_order 
FROM [Size] where ranked_order = 1
```

the result I got:

> ```
> Product   StatusId    ProductID   ranked_order 
>     62    60                75    1
>     62    60                79    1
>     62    60                23    1
>     62    60                 7    1
> ```

here as subquery:

```
SELECT  [Product], [StatusId], [ProductId],ranked_order
       FROM (
SELECT [Product], [StatusId], [ProductId],
                   DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [Product] ORDER BY [RequestId] DESC) ranked_order 
          FROM [Size]) pz  where ranked_order = 1
```

and it returns the data but there are some missing products.

so I have added the following condition `where ProductId in (1,2,3)` to trace the error for some missing products and I noticed the rank changes from 1 to 2.

and as I mentioned before it appears if the products are related only to one RequestId.

> ```
> Product   StatusId    ProductID   ranked_order 
>     62    60                75    2
>     62    60                79    2
>     62    60                23    2
>     62    60                 7    2
> ```

Answer (score 0):

In your first query applies the condition `where ProductId in (1,2,3)` before the `dense_rank` is calculated, because they appear in the same query.

In the second query, you calculate the `dense_rank` first, in the sub-query, then apply `where ProductId in (1,2,3)` in the outer query. Presumably your table contains data that would be ranked first before that condition is applied.

Comment: the original condition is(where ranked_order = 1), but since it return nothing I have add the ProductId condition to trace the change of the rank so I noticed that is rank with 2 instead of 1. And since there is only one request it must rank with 1 why 2?